# How to merge contours in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

Ok guys I have been working on this project for quite some time now.

I am building this bot that plays the chrome dinosaur game. So I tried other methods to detect the characters like matchTemplate and even made my own algorithm to locate the objects, but I like this one (findcontours) the most.

Here's what I have:

[image: What my program sees]

Can anyone help me find out how I should merge the two rectangles of the cacti?

```
img = screen_cap()
roi = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(roi,127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
first = True
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 200: #filtering contours
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w/h < 4: # filtering even more
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

Comment: What's stopping you from checking if a bounding box's pixel locations are near the locations of other bounding boxes and if so, extending the width and height of the leftmost one?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds  He said merge contours, so if the rectangles were offset, or there were multiple contours I'm not sure if they just want the bounding box or the actual lines between contours to disappear (such that they would be arbitrary axis aligned polygons)

Comment: @snb Indeed it is vague, in the title it asks to merge the contours but in the question it asks to merge the bounding rects. Could use clustering possibly to find near contours.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds  I am sorry that the question was vague. What i want to do is make the computer think both the cactuses as one single entity and be in one bounding box, must be a rectangle. Am I clear enough yet? I am also trying to implement it myself. Just asking here to know if there are native opencv methods.

Comment: @snb look up...

Comment: I understand that you want them to be one object but it's not clear what you want that object to be. Should it be a binary image? Should it be a set of every pixel locations only from the cactus and not around them or between them? Should it be just a rectangle around them (ie you only need the top left point and width or height)?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds i only need a rectangle that represents both cactuses.

Comment: If you stick with contours, then you can classify the rectangles on whether they're the dinosaur or cactus based on their width. Then if they're cacti, you can look to see if the endpoints of the box are near each other. You create a bounding rect, get the four endpoints of the box (since you have one point and the h and w), and then check to see if those points are near other cacti rectangles that you have processed already.

Comment: I found an interesting solution here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/opencv-c-connect-nearby-contours-based-on-distance-between-them/2889#2889?newreg=c12ad92a45c34b7dabbf977555c29da3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question and seems like it has not been answered properly yet (apologies to fellow SOers who did it partially in comments though). To me it seems like the questioner has a two-part question:

1. Is there a opencv function that merges two rectangles?

Answer to this question is yes and no. Let me be clear; yes if you are using opencv C++ bindings. Simple & can be used to take a union and | for intersection of two rects. But Python bindings lack those functions.

2. How to then do it in Python?

   ```
   def union(a,b):
       x = min(a[0], b[0])
       y = min(a[1], b[1])
       w = max(a[0]+a[2], b[0]+b[2]) - x
       h = max(a[1]+a[3], b[1]+b[3]) - y
       return (x, y, w, h)

   def intersection(a,b):
       x = max(a[0], b[0])
       y = max(a[1], b[1])
       w = min(a[0]+a[2], b[0]+b[2]) - x
       h = min(a[1]+a[3], b[1]+b[3]) - y
       if w<0 or h<0: return () # or (0,0,0,0) ?
       return (x, y, w, h)
       # Please remember a and b are rects.
   ```

Source Code Credit: [OpenCV union and intersaction on rects](https://answers.opencv.org/question/90455/how-to-perform-intersection-or-union-operations-on-a-rect-in-python/)

Comment: what if it was multiple contours and they are very close to each other, is there a way to merge them into one contour ?

Comment: @abss, you just need to iterate over them to merge them. Alternately you can use morphological dilation on your binary image itself before finding contours, depending on what works best for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, The problem is that, my contours that I want to merge, they are so close that they look like they are one, but there's  a very small gab between them, and there's a bit of noise around them so using dilation will include the noise into the contours, I have already filtered the image as much as I can, but I can't remove them completely

Comment: @abss, it would be hard to tell you what to do to process the images you have until you post them for others to have a look. If your foreground contours are larger than a certain size as compared to noise then you can filter out smaller contours using cv2.ContourArea() function, redrawing the foreground contours and then running morphological dilation.

Comment: yea I understand, I'm currently still trying to  do some filtering, if I run out of idea I will post  my question with the image. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @abss the usual process is to use morphological _closing_ which dilates the masks so they merge, then erodes them so they shrink back to their original size (but now with the holes/gaps filled).

Answer (score 15):

Sorry to be a little late to the party. However if I google "merge opencv contours" I find this; and I think there should be an answer.

You can merge any two contours by one of those recipes:

- Get a list of points of each contour
- append them
- force them into cv2 contour format
- get cv2.convexHull of that if you don't care too much about the details.

If you don't like the result of convexHull because the concave parts of the contours are important, then follow this recipe instead:

- Get a list of points of each contour
- append them
- get a common center
- sort all the points in clockwise order around the center
- force them into cv2 contour format

If the two contours have a lot of concave shapes in them, this could yield a zigzag-pattern as the recipe goes through both contours disregarding their original structure. If that's the case, you need to follow a third recipe:

- Get a list of points of each contour
- get a common center
- delete points of each contour which are inside the other contour
- find the point which is closest to the common center in each contour.
- go through the first contour as it is listed until you hit the closest point.
- Then switch to the other list, starting from the closest point you go clockwise through the other contour until it is used up
- switch back to the first contour and append the rest of their points.
- force them into cv2 contour format

The next-more-complicated case is, if you have multiple intersections between the contours and you want to preserve the holes between the two. Then it's better to make a black image and draw the contours in white via `cv2.fillPoly()`; then get the contours back out via `cv2.findContours()`

I sketched some steps for the first two recipes here

#### get a list of points of each contour:

```
import cv2
list_of_pts = [] 
for ctr in ctrs_to_merge:
    list_of_pts += [pt[0] for pt in ctr]
```

#### order points clockwise

I use the function of [this really great posting of MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855695/sorting-list-of-two-dimensional-coordinates-by-clockwise-angle-using-python) to order the points in clockwise order.

```
class clockwise_angle_and_distance():
    '''
    A class to tell if point is clockwise from origin or not.
    This helps if one wants to use sorted() on a list of points.

    Parameters
    ----------
    point : ndarray or list, like [x, y]. The point "to where" we g0
    self.origin : ndarray or list, like [x, y]. The center around which we go
    refvec : ndarray or list, like [x, y]. The direction of reference

    use: 
        instantiate with an origin, then call the instance during sort
    reference: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855695/sorting-list-of-two-dimensional-coordinates-by-clockwise-angle-using-python

    Returns
    -------
    angle
    
    distance
    

    '''
    def __init__(self, origin):
        self.origin = origin

    def __call__(self, point, refvec = [0, 1]):
        if self.origin is None:
            raise NameError("clockwise sorting needs an origin. Please set origin.")
        # Vector between point and the origin: v = p - o
        vector = [point[0]-self.origin[0], point[1]-self.origin[1]]
        # Length of vector: ||v||
        lenvector = np.linalg.norm(vector[0] - vector[1])
        # If length is zero there is no angle
        if lenvector == 0:
            return -pi, 0
        # Normalize vector: v/||v||
        normalized = [vector[0]/lenvector, vector[1]/lenvector]
        dotprod  = normalized[0]*refvec[0] + normalized[1]*refvec[1] # x1*x2 + y1*y2
        diffprod = refvec[1]*normalized[0] - refvec[0]*normalized[1] # x1*y2 - y1*x2
        angle = atan2(diffprod, dotprod)
        # Negative angles represent counter-clockwise angles so we need to 
        # subtract them from 2*pi (360 degrees)
        if angle < 0:
            return 2*pi+angle, lenvector
        # I return first the angle because that's the primary sorting criterium
        # but if two vectors have the same angle then the shorter distance 
        # should come first.
        return angle, lenvector

center_pt = np.array(list_of_pts).mean(axis = 0) # get origin
clock_ang_dist = clockwise_angle_and_distance(origin) # set origin
list_of_pts = sorted(list_of_pts, key=clock_ang_dist) # use to sort
```

#### force a list of points into cv2 format

```
import numpy as np
ctr = np.array(list_of_pts).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
```

#### merge them with `cv2.convexHull` instead

If you use this then there is no need to order the points clockwise. However, the convexHull might lose some contour properties because it does not preserve concave corners of your contour.

```
# get a list of points
# force the list of points into cv2 format and then
ctr = cv2.convexHull(ctr) # done.
```

I think the function to merge two contours should be a content of the opencv library. The recipe is quite straightforward and it is sad that many programmers, using opencv, will have to boilerplate code this.

Comment: Thank you Anderas, this is quite helpful!

Comment: There is a great and very compact implementation of a function to order points clockwise here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874392/4438445

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to merge contours is to stack them

```
contours = np.vstack(contours)
```

in your case(for example to stack contours 5 and 6):

```
contours = np.vstack([contours[5], contours[6]])
```